# Azure Service Bus message abandon and dead letter queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

- In Azure Service Bus topic, I am having two subscriptions
  subscription1 and subscription2. I am sending one message to topic.
  In subscription1 the message got abandoned and in subscription2 the
  message got processed. Whether the abandoned message in subscription1
  will again be sent to both subscriptions or only subscription in
  which it got abandoned.
- I am also a little bit confused whether the dead letter queue will be common
  for all subscriptions or each subscription will have a separate dead
  letter queue?

Please clarify me on the above two points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subcriptions are independent. `Abandon` affects just the one where it was abandoned, and dead letter queues are separate.

One caveat is that if you want to resubmit messages from DLQ, you can't send them directly to the corresponding subscription, it has to go through the topic again.

Comment: Whether there is any way to configure the topic to automatically submit messages from dead letter queue to topic .

Comment: @ArvindA No. That doesn't make much sense to me. Just Abandon in this case, and increase MaxDeliveryCount to whatever value you need.

Comment: In my case iam using logic apps to receive messages from service bus topic with peek lock.so how can I receive messages from dead letter queue.

Comment: It's best to put additional questions in separate SO questions (or find existing one)